# Collectionview reload function not run inside a tableviewcell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I created a collectionview inside a tableviewcell. I passed the data to the class of the tableviewcell. I tried to call the collectionview reload function, but the function never runs.

On cell class:

```
TableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource 

    @IBOutlet weak var statCollection: UICollectionView!
    var collectionArray = [] // This creates the collection cells

    //DELEGATE SELF (datasource, delegate) at awakeFromNib()

    func loadItems(){
        print("load2")
        self.statelem = self.selectedStatparent?.statelements.sorted(byKeyPath: "statname", ascending: true)
        print("Elem: \(self.statelem?.count)") //=4
         DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            self.statCollection.reloadData()
        })       
    }
```

Creating cells, and call the function (on ViewController):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = statTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! StatTableViewCell
    cell.statcategoryName.text = statkategoria?[indexPath.row].Categoryname
    cell.selectedStatparent = statkategoria?[indexPath.row]
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        cell.loadItems()
    })
    return cell
}
```

Comment: post full UITableViewCell

Comment: Dont make a async call inside cellForRow and dont call reload inside cell.. Make use of delegate. Your controller should handle that.